# SUBSELECT to LIMIT before GROUP BY / HAVING?

Tags: mysql, performance, limit, subquery

I was just asking myself, if this makes sense:

I have a query that joins with a couple of tables, groups the result (to use `GROUP_CONCAT` on some columns), and then filters out some results with `HAVING`, before sorting them with `ORDER BY`

The `LIMIT`, is the last statement here - so basically, the limit only takes effect when `HAVING` is going through the results, right?

I was asking myself - what if I already Limit the `FROM` part, by doing a `SUBSELECT` with the same `LIMIT`? But it's not that simple, it gets a bit more complicated:

It's hard to come up with an example that makes sense, I only have a bad one:

A car has always 4 wheels, every wheel has an own table row. So it doesnt make sense to search past the first 4 wheels - I know that, MySQL probably doesnt. So having `LIMIT 4` after the `HAVING`, would mean that mysql searches trough the whole table (listing millions of wheels) even if it could have stopped at the 4th.

Basically, my question is - does a `SUBSELECT` make sense in query below?

without `SUBSELECT`:

```
SELECT    *
FROM      carwheel
LEFT JOIN ... ON ...
LEFT JOIN ... ON ...
LEFT JOIN ... ON ...
WHERE     ...
GROUP BY  ...
HAVING    ...
ORDER BY  ...
LIMIT     4
```

with `SUBSELECT`:

```
SELECT   *
FROM     (
             SELECT *
             FROM   carwheel
             WHERE  ... -- (first, simple filter)
             LIMIT  4
         ) AS carwheel
LEFT JOIN ... ON ...
LEFT JOIN ... ON ...
LEFT JOIN ... ON ...
WHERE     ...
GROUP BY  ...
HAVING    ...
ORDER BY  ...
LIMIT     4 -- (does it make sense, to do it twice?)
```

I've read that even adding `LIMIT 1` when you expect a single row, makes a lot of sense since MySQL stops to look for more rows after finding the first one. That's the whole reason I'm thinking about the subselect, since MySQL will look trough the whole `carwheel` table, instead of stopping at the 4th, if the `LIMIT` takes only effect after `HAVING`, right?

Comment: If your table is properly indexed, it shouldn't have to search through millions of rows to find the 4 you care about, so the LIMIT clause won't have much effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get different results, because the order is undefined when you limit in the from subselect. You get four rows in both cases, but in one case you might get rows 7, 14, 23, 8 and in another case you might get rows 1, 2, 88, 17. So it makes sense to limit the result set in order to minimize traffic, for example, but keep in mind that, depending on where you limit, you get different rows.

*Edit*:

After your clarification, it makes sense to pre-filter the rows in your from clause, because then the join has less rows to process. The second limit is useful too, because with the `left join`s you can get more than four rows in your result set.

But to be sure, which one is better, do an `explain select ...` with both queries. Then, you can compare both selects and see which one is more efficient.

Comment: But his condition is that there are only 4 matching rows to begin with (remember, he said "a car only has 4 wheels"), so how can he get different rows?

Comment: @Barmar Yes, a *car* has only four wheels, but his table has millions of rows. So he might get different rows regardless, because in the from subselect he hasn't done neither the `join`s, `group by`, nor the `order by`.

Comment: That problem actually isnt an issue in my case, since the 'WHERE' inside the subselect, already selects the correct 4 rows. The HAVING and JOINs only are there, to filter out some of the rows that I dont need - that's the reason why I was thinking about a SUBSELECT there, I basically already know the car, and the 4 wheels, but dont know yet wich of them to 'drop'

Comment: @Katai Then this is some special case, where you could drop everything but the from subselect.

Comment: sorry, english isnt my native language so I may wrote something incorrectly: what I mean, is: I dont know wich wheel to 'drop'. The JOINs / HAVING basically filter out some of those 4 wheels (lets say, wich wheel is damaged, for example) - so I need to get all 4 wheels from car A first, and then JOIN it with other records of other tables to find out wich of the 4 wheels I really need